# Where do I begin trying to resolve an Event ID 6398 Timer error in a TFS/SharePoint suite?

Tags: sharepoint-server, timer-jobs, tfs

SharePoint Server 2013 SP1, TFS2013, SQL Server 2012 Standard SP2

Running in Hyper-V on a Server 2012 R2 vm

I receive this error at a regular intervals such as every hour, or during startup/shutdown (I'm still configuring the overall system).  I read this [link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc561011(v=office.12).aspx), but didn't quite understand how to complete the diagnosis.  This is the complete Event report:

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        Microsoft-SharePoint Products-SharePoint Foundation
Date:          7/15/2015 3:12:53 PM
Event ID:      6398
Task Category: Timer
Level:         Critical
Keywords:      
User:          <mydomain>\tfsreports
Computer:      vsvr-tfs01.<mydomain>.local
Description:

The Execute method of job definition 
 Microsoft.Office.RecordsManagement.Preservation.PreservationJobDefinition 
(ID eb94b542-1cc3-4c91-8c7d-eef48f7f56ca) threw an exception. More information is included below.

The search request was unable to connect to the Search Service.
```

Could someone get me started with this?  Or if it is a familiar error perhaps guide me to resolving it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To resolve above issue, please follow steps below:

1. Navigate to SharePoint 2013 Central Administration >> Monitoring >> Review Job Definition
2. Select All from drop down
3. Find eDiscovery In-Place Hold Processing timer job. Click on it.
4. Click on Disable